# Magento customer can't log in

Tags: magento, logging

I just migrated my website. But I got a problem.

My customers can't log in to their account. When click log in on log-in page.
http://www.mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/
It should be log in on their account but it redirects the same page.

Please Help me how to fix that?

Comment: How are you storing session data?

Comment: @input I'm very new to magento. do you mean in local.xml right? if yes <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>

Comment: Are there lots of files in /var/session/?

Comment: Does your web server have write access?

Comment: @input I can only use Cpanel to edit file.

Answer (score 24):

After upgrading to Magento 1.8.1 you need to edit your existing template files.

The files listed below need te be change in order to be compatible with Magento 1.8.1. If they exist in your custom theme, compare them to the original `base/default/template` files.

- `your_package/your_theme/template/customer/form/newsletter.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/customer/form/login.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/customer/form/edit.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/customer/address/edit.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/whishlist/view.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/whishlist/sharing.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/review/form.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/multishipping/overview.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/sendfriend/send.phtml`
- `your_package/your_theme/template/sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml`

Edit these files and add `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` after the `<form ...>` open tag

Comment: Man, you have just saved my day. Come to Slovenia and I will pay you a beer :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. TYFM !

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: `Web_Customer.xml` - Enabling custom module:

```xml
<?xml version=”1.0″?>
<config>
<modules>
<Web_Customer>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</Web_Customer>
</modules>
</config>
```

Step 2: `config.xml` – Configuration for our module:

```xml
<?xml version=”1.0″?>
<config>
<modules>
<Web_Customer>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</Web_Customer>
</modules>
<frontend>
<routers>
<customer><!– Name of core module to be overridden–>
<args>
<modules>
<Web_Customer before=”Mage_Customer”>Web_Customer</Web_Customer><!– Tell Magento to call our custom module before the Mage/Checkout module –>
</modules>
</args>
</customer>
</routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Step 3: Add the following code to line 139 just after the opening of `loginPostAction()` in `AccountController.php`

```php
<?php
require_once(“Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php”);
class Web_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_CUstomer_AccountController{
public function loginPostAction()
{
// generate form_key if missing or invalid
if (!($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam(‘form_key’, null)) || $formKey != Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->getFormKey()) {
$this->getRequest()->setParams(array(‘form_key’ =>Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->getFormKey()));
}

//Note*
// rest code is same as from Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
}
}
?>
```

After completing, don’t forget to clear Magento cache.

Comment: i too had same issue when upgrade to 1.8.1.0.so i tried this.its working for me.

Comment: many thanks for the solution.I just found that this errors come with magento 1.8.1 version. So this is a solution for this problem check this out  http://blueclawecommerce.co.uk/blog/fix-customer-cannot-login-to-magento-1-8-1/

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `template/customer/form/login.phtml` and `template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml` and under

  ```
  <ul class="form-list">
  ```
- Add the following code in the login form

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<? echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
  ```

OR, if you are using the login form in several places with different template files

- Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`
- Open the AccountController.php that you have copied to local and add the following code to line 139 just after the opening of loginPostAction()

  ```
  // generate form_key if missing or invalid
  if (!($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', null)) || $formKey != Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()) {
      $this->getRequest()->setParams(array('form_key' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));
  }
  ```

http://www.blueclawsearch.co.uk/blog/2013/12/12/fix-customer-cannot-login-to-magento-1-8-1/

Comment: This is a bad idea. You will be defeating the purpose of having a form_key in the first place.