# Magento Login Fails

Tags: magento

I installed Magento on my localhost. When I try to log in the admin and enter the correct username and password, I get redirected to the login page again with the URL:

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin/index/index/key/e88edc351f2b6e669632765634b999f1/
```

Notice the two "index" segments in the URL. I also don't get an error.

However, when I purposely put in the wrong username and password, I'm redirected to the same page (same URL), but with the error:

```
Invalid User Name or Password.
```

Any idea what's wrong? I'm using Magento 1.8.1.0.

Comment: Every time you logout from Magento Admin Panel you get `index.php/admin/index/index/. I mean that double index is not weird. It redirects you to the indexAction of the indexController of Admin. Have you tried to login as customer in frontend. If you can't then most likely is a session configuration problem.

Comment: OK, I'm new to Magento. I didn't realize that the double "index" is normal. I don't know how to login as a customer. This is a fresh install on my localhost. I think I only have the admin account right? Is there a default customer account I can try?

Comment: Same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565688/magento-customer-cant-log-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 1.3 and below

Find app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php. in your Magento install folder. Comment out the lines (see below) 80 to 83. The line number may vary. You have to comment the comma (,) in line:

> `$this→getCookie()→getPath(), set session cookie params
>   session_set_cookie_params( $this→getCookie()→getLifetime(),
>   $this→getCookie()→getPath() , $this→getCookie()→getDomain(),
>   $this→getCookie()→isSecure(), $this→getCookie()→getHttponly() );`

For Magento 1.4 and above:

Find

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

. and look for line 86 to 98

> if (!$cookieParams[’httponly’]) { unset($cookieParams[’httponly’]); if
>   (!$cookieParams[’secure’]) { unset($cookieParams[’secure’]); if
>   (!$cookieParams[’domain’]) { unset($cookieParams[’domain’]); } } } if
>   (isset($cookieParams[’domain’])) { $cookieParams[’domain’] =
>   $cookie→getDomain(); }

For details see the [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_fix_login_for_admin_on_local_install#dokuwiki__top)

Comment: For 1.8.1.0, they were lines 96-108. I assume this is only a problem with localhost? I'm just now exploring Magento.

Comment: yes you are right.I already solved the same issue multiple time using this way.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run with your IP like `http://127.0.0.1/magento/`

Also before that change 2 parameters value in **core_config_data** table 
find path "web/unsecure/base_url" and change above value `http://127.0.0.1/magento/`
same should be for "web/secure/base_url"

clear cache and sessions.

Hope this help