# Login Functionality not working after magento upgrading from 1.8 to 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I have upgraded my magento(1.8) to newer version 1.9. Suddently it's stopped working for login functionality and it's redirecting to the same page.

And i checked the files

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php & app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php
```

In the function `_validateFormKey()` **form-key** is not setting and it's coming null. I googled for this issue and tried the below solutions 
But these links are also not useful to me. Can u help me to sort out this issue?

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565688/magento-customer-cant-log-in) &
[here also](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9)

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you put whithin form element in checkout/onepage/login.phtml and customer/form/login.phtml

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Or you can try solution described here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22363/erratic-cookie-related-login-problem

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be caused by caching. You can try delete all files in */var/session* or log in using another browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Cache and indexing issue.

1. Delete your cache manually by navigating to the var and delete the cache folder from there and refresh the website and check the var folder again if it is creating the cache folder over there then it is ok, other wise provide the 777 permission to the var folder.
2. Delete all your index files from the var/locks folder and reindex the data from the Magento admin.
3. Check if there is `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` below the `<form>`. If it is missing put the code below all the forms.

Hope it helps,

Thanks

Comment: Hello Pawan, Thanks for answering but i already tried in this way, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Mention log in issue happened with Chrome , Open file

```
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php
```

Comment line no : 110 below function

call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);

If this works then , place the same file in local in same path.

Answer (score 0):

Take the login.php file from Your magento directory **template/persistent/customer/form/login.php**. Put this below snippet after the `<form>` tag.

```
 <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
```

Please try

Answer (score 0):

I just updated cookie domain in cookie management.

To do this go to **Admin > System > Configurations > Web > Session Cookie Management.**

Update cookie domain as xxxxxxxx.com. I did this and tested in various browsers and not able to see the error again. Try this.

Answer (score -1):

Its very useful for this answer

getBlockHtml('formkey')?>